# Cassandra CQL unable to insert (no viable alternative at input)

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra, cql

After setup cassandra (0.8.4) and tested with insert and select via CLI, i move on to JDBC (1.0.3) with CQL.

This is where, i encounter SQLException on following code, any idea?

```
Connection conn =  DriverManager.getConnection(url);             

String sql = "INSERT INTO row (KEY, first, last, age) VALUES ( 'Jones', 'Jones', 'Lang', '32');"; // internal error
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute(sql);
```

The exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: line 1:22 no viable alternative at input 'first'
at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.execute(CassandraStatement.java:160)
at Cassandra.Insert.main(Insert.java:22)
```

Answer (score 8):

`first` is a CQL keyword, you need to put it in quotes.  Try:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO row ('KEY', 'first', 'last', 'age') VALUES ( 'Jones', 'Jones', 'Lang', '32');";
```

Comment: Tryed those in CQL console, but it doesn't work for me:

`cqlsh:testfamily> INSERT INTO tags ('KEY', 'first', 'last', 'age') VALUES ( 'Jones', 'Jones', 'Lang', '32');
Bad Request: line 1:42 no viable alternative at input 'age'`

Comment: This error refers to a parsing problem. The real underlying issue is that it is expecting an integer for 'age' but you are passing it a string.